# Why last element of input is missing in Scanner?

Tags: java, input, stdin, delimiter

I use IntelliJ and I have a problem with a Scanner. Last element from the input is missing in the output. Any ideas?

Input: `1, 2, 3`
Output: `1, 2`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(", ");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the Scanner is not done reading `System.in`: the stdin stream is not closed, and still waiting for end of token (next occurrence of `", "`), or end of stream.

You also need to change `sc.hasNext()` to `sc.hasNextInt()` because you consume `sc.nextInt()`.

Then you could execute your program on the command line, it should show the 3 correctly:

```
echo -n "1, 2, 3" | java MyScannerExample
```

However:

```
echo "1, 2, 3" | java MyScannerExample
```

will *not* show the 3 because the input string is actually `"1, 2, 3\n"`, so the last token is `"3\n"` which is not an integer.